# creating an updating jqgrid table from websocket source

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I am struggling a bit with where to start, I am in the process of doing a websocket project, I have the server coded which pushes messages in realtime to a websocket client running jQuery and HTML5. I have set the server up to pass across JSON messages like the below.

```
{"timestamp":"2015-01-12T17:22:40.4372664+11:00","code":0012345,"parsedname":" (NAME)","priority":"AB","message":"THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE"}
```

These messages show up fine on the websocket page, but now I want to display them in a more friendly way. Whilst I am fine with vb.net this kind of programming is way out of my area and I am wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of some simple code examples which would allow me to update a table in realtime as a json message is recieved by the websocket client.

I had a quick look on the net, but I can either find only partial examples or overly complex examples. I should clarify I am not looking for someone to do it for me, just to help me get a better understanding on how to best do it and to point me in the direction of some code samples.

From what I can see it looks like jqgrid might be suitable, but I don't know how to bind it to a websocket, and how to go from there.

From the demo's it looks like something like this below should work, but how do I change the source to the websockets json strings, and once done, how do I then update the table. I should clarify each new message is 1 json string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "example.php",
        datatype: "xml",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["timestamp", "code", "name", "message"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "timestamp", width: 55 },
            { name: "code", width: 90 },
            { name: "name", width: 80, align: "right" },
            { name: "message", width: 80, align: "right" }
        ],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: "invid",
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "My first grid"
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Many thanks,

Thanks for the tips, I have tried the samples and combined them but having no real luck so far :(

Travis.

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Info Stream (TEST)</title>
        <link href="https://www.guriddo.net/demo/css/trirand/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.guriddo.net/demo/js/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.guriddo.net/demo/js/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
            var noSupportMessage = "Your browser cannot support WebSocket!";
            var ws;

            function appendMessage(message) {
                $('body').append(message);
            }

            function connectSocketServer() {
                var support = "MozWebSocket" in window ? 'MozWebSocket' : ("WebSocket" in window ? 'WebSocket' : null);

                if (support === null) {
                    appendMessage("* " + noSupportMessage + "<br/>");
                    return;
                }

                appendMessage("* Connecting to server ..<br/>");
                // create a new websocket and connect
                ws = new window[support]('ws://address.com:2012/');

                // when data is comming from the server, this metod is called
                ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                    makegrid(evt.data);
                };

                // when the connection is established, this method is called
                ws.onopen = function () {
                    appendMessage('* Connection open<br/>');
                };

                // when the connection is closed, this method is called
                ws.onclose = function () {
                    appendMessage('* Connection closed<br/>');
                };
            }

            function disconnectWebSocket() {
                if (ws) {
                    ws.close();
                }
            }

            function connectWebSocket() {
                connectSocketServer();
            }



            window.onload = function () {
  connectWebSocket();
  };

  function makeGrid(data){
    var json = [data]; // now this is local data
     $("#list").jqGrid({
            datastr: data, // so you should use datastr instead of url with localdata
            datatype: "jsonstring", // and dataype should be jsonstring with local data
            colNames: ["timestamp", "capcode", "parsedname", "message"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "timestamp", width: 400 },
                { name: "capcode", width: 200 },
                { name: "parsedname", width: 200, align: "right" },
                { name: "message", width: 200, align: "right" }
            ],
            pager: "#pager",
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: "invid",
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            caption: "Pager Messages"
        }); 
             };

    </script>
    </head>


    <body>
<table id='list'></table>
<div id='pager'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `datatype: "xml",` change it to `datatype: "json",` and return json like this: `[{}]` an array of object/s.

Answer (score 0):

your data type should be json

```
datatype: "json"
```

everything else looks fine.

Comment: I am not sure if it will help, but I have set the server up to randomly generate data at the address ws:\\123.2.21.183:2012, hopefully someone can see the no doubt silly mistake I am making

Answer (score 0):

Try this this is a sample demo with your json and the js object should have to be in `[]`:

```js
var data = [{"timestamp":"2015-01-12T17:22:40.4372664+11:00","code":0012345,"parsedname":" (NAME)","priority":"AB","message":"THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE"}];
    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            datastr: data,
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            mtype: "GET",
            colNames: ["timestamp", "code", "name", "message"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "timestamp", width: 400 },
                { name: "code", width: 200 },
                { name: "name", width: 200, align: "right" },
                { name: "message", width: 200, align: "right" }
            ],
            pager: "#pager",
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: "invid",
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            caption: "My first grid"
        }); 
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://www.guriddo.net/demo/css/trirand/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.guriddo.net/demo/js/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.guriddo.net/demo/js/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>



<table id='list'></table>
<div id='pager'></div>
```

---

Another way is this, you can have a jquery ajax call to get the object you are getting and push that object in array and pass the array to the jqgrid like this:

```
$.getJSON('example.php', function(data){
    makeGrid(data);
});
```

and your function `makeGrid()`:

```
function makeGrid(data){
    var json = [data]; // now this is local data

     $("#list").jqGrid({
            datastr: data, // so you should use datastr instead of url with localdata
            datatype: "jsonstring", // and dataype should be jsonstring with local data
           ....
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have added some code sample tthat I have used but had no luck so far :(.

Comment: You need to move the `window.onload` call outside of `makeGrid()` function.

Comment: Thanks Jai, I am closer but the table still does not generate let alone self-update when new data comes through :(

Comment: So close yet so far, from my tests if I hard code the JSON string in then it works fine, however if I use the makeGrid and pass the data across then it does not work :(.

Comment: `makegrid(evt.data);` so you meant to say data is not passing through, you can check it with `console.log(evt.data)` if this logs out your json then it is going in else there might be other issue. you can look in the console for the errors.

Comment: It is passing through on the console, with no errors, and the one row + the table gets created but there is no data in the table.

Comment: check the keys then is it same as you posted in the question.

Comment: When i pass a string through, on the webpage it shows as normal, but on the console it shows as: ["{"timestamp":"2015-01-12T22:41:31.5615041+11:00","…ssionID is:15168a94-af43-47d5-a6bf-bf51f2642385"}"]            I am confused, could the " at the start be causing that, and if so what would be adding it as it is not being added from the server side.

Comment: headers are all good, I removed the brackets from the [data] and the json string looks fine on console, still not being entered into the table though (and no errors reported).:   {"timestamp":"2015-01-12T22:53:11.8715596+11:00","capcode":1,"parsedname":"ADMIN","priority":"ADMIN","message":"Your SessionID is:63f0cf36-5b6e-4260-8290-24e73abc4050"}

Comment: Just wondering if there is any other issue it might be, it comes through the console log fine, and they key's are right but it still does not show up :(, if I hard code it in the variable string then it works fine just not when coming from the websocket :(